# How to upload a file using AsyncHttpClient with basicAuth?

Tags: java, android, file-upload, upload, android-async-http

the request must be post type, and when I tried AsyncHttpClient returns me ClientProtocolException Caused by NonRepeatableRequestException

my code:

```
        if (checkIfClientIsReady(act)) {
        try {
            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("name", name);
        params.put("document", file);
```

//          params.put("document", new FileInputStream(file), name, "image/png");

```
        client.post(act, getAbsoluteUrl("/user-documents"), params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
                intf.onRequestStart(Constant.REQUEST_BILL_SEND);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable error, String content) {
                super.onFailure(error, content);
                intf.onRequestFailure(Constant.REQUEST_BILL_SEND, error, content);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, String content) {
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, content);
                intf.onRequestSuccess(Constant.REQUEST_BILL_SEND, statusCode, content);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                super.onFinish();
                intf.onRequestFinish(Constant.REQUEST_BILL_SEND);
            }
        });
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            DocUtils.loge("bug ici");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: yes and no, I managed to redo my query complete without asynchttpclient and use it with httpmime-4.2.3.jar